# Angular 2 bind properties

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular2, for that I'm creating an example code.

I have a reusable component `Card` which should receive a parameter:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: '../templates/card.html'
})

export class Card {
    @Input() title;
}
```

that title parameter should be a `string`.

This is the html template for this component so far:

```
<div class='card'>
  {{ title }}
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

and from other component I'm calling it like this:

```
<card
  [title]='Enter your raw json'>
  Example
</card>
```

I'm getting this error in the console (beside a lot others):

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'your' at column 7 in [Enter your raw json] in JsonTextInput@1:2 ("<card
  [ERROR ->][title]='Enter your raw json'>
  Example
</card>"): JsonTextInput@1:2
```

What is wrong with the property binding?

Comment: Try "'enter your json'". I think you need to specify that you are using a string as parameter having single quotes within Doyle qoutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use property binding, Angular2's template parser will interpret the content as a property of your component class:

```
@Component({
  template: `<card [title]="property"> ... </card>`,
  ...
})
class SomethingComponent {
  property = 'something'; // this will be bound to the title input of card
}
```

If you want to pass a string literal to a property binding, put it inside single quotes, like this:

```
[title]="'some title'"
```